# Fetch facebook albums and cover photos

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Inside my app, I let users to upload photos from Facebook. So first I fetch all user albums with:

```
new Request(session, "/me/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
}
};
```

and then I'm using an Adapter to show every album inside a GridView, so inside the getView method I call [/{album-id}/picture](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/album/picture), but I don't know how to parse the Response. What I have to do with the Response object to display the image inside an ImageView? Is there any better way to do this?

This is how I made the request

```
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("type", "thumbnail");
                String albumid = albums.get(position);
                new Request(session, "/"+ albumid +"/picture",
                        params, HttpMethod.GET, 
                        new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                    }
                }
                        ).executeAsync();
```

And this is what I get:

> {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject:
>   GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject,
>   state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"����\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0001\u0000\u0000��\u0000\u0004*\u0000��\u0002\u001cICC_PROFILE\u0000\u0001\u0001\u0000\u0000\u0002"}},
>   error: null, isFromCache:false}

Answer (score 1):

For Fetching facebook albums use this

```
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
                //params.putString("fields", "photos.limit(10),name,count");
                params.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                params.putString("limit", "1000");
                //me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me/albums",params ,"GET"));
                System.out.println("params are: "+params);

                if(facebook.getAccessToken()!= null)
                {
                    me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me/albums",params ,"GET"));
                }

                fbAlbumList.clear();
                try {
                    //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(respons);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = me.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        FbAlbumBean bean = new FbAlbumBean();
                        bean.albumId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                        bean.albumName = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                        if(i!=0)
                        {
                        bean.coverId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("cover_photo");
                        bean.albumCount = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("count")+"";
                        }
                        fbAlbumList.add(bean);
                    }
```

And for fetching Photos by albumId

```
public void fetchPhotosFromAlbumId(final String album_id, Activity activity){

    //new FetchAsyncTask().execute(album_id);

    progressDialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(activity,"", "Please wait...");
    System.out.println("progress dialog: "+progressDialog1);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();

            JSONObject me;
            try {
                fbPhotosList.clear();
                String offset1 = String.valueOf(offset+100);
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("limit", "1000");
                params.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());

                //me = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me/albums",params ,"GET"));
                me = new JSONObject(facebook.request(album_id+"/photos",params ,"GET"));
                System.out.println(me);

                JSONArray jsonArray = me.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    CameraRollBean bean = new CameraRollBean();
                    bean.filePath = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("source");
                    bean.showRight_IB = false;
                    fbPhotosList.add(bean); 
                }
                System.out.println("size of fb album: "+fbAlbumList.size());
                FbAlbumsScreen.fromFbScreen = true;
                Intent intent = new Intent(_activity, CameraRollScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("album_id", album_id);
                _activity.startActivity(intent);


                if(progressDialog1!=null)
                    progressDialog1.cancel();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    progressDialog1.show();
}
```

Comment: great, but how you fetch the image located in bean.coverId? I need to display every album with his cover.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely getting back a HTTP redirect to the image URL (this would be useable in an `<img>` tag on a website, for example)

This is documented in the [Album documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/album/picture):

`Fields
No fields are returned, instead you will receive the image file itself.`

What you probably need to do is request the cover photo specifically, with a call like:

`/<version>/<album id>?fields=cover_photo` - Once you have the ID you can request the [Photo object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo)'s details and take the most appropriately sized source image from the response

Comment: but if I want to display a grid with all the albums names and covers I would have to make a request for every album in order to get the url from the photo object and then download the photo?

Comment: You could either fetch the bytes of the image using /picture (as you're doing now, but your code is expecting a string) or fetch the image URLs in a batch, and load them into the view the same way you're trying to do in your sample code